# .NET MVC 4 - Best practices for keeping state of a list of selected objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

This should be an easy one, but without ViewState, I'm clueless here (I've been babied with WebForms for too long, I know!).

My scenario:

**View**

```
 @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
    <tr>
       <td>@Html.ActionLink("Compare", "Compare", new { id = product.ProductId })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Compare(int id = 0)
{
        var product = SelectProduct(id); // selects the product from a list of cached products.

        if (product != null)
        {
           // _productDetails is a Model specifically for my View.
            _productDetails.ComparedProducts.Add(product);
        }

        return View("Index", _productDetails);
}
```

Obviously, when you click on "Compare" for each item, it'll add to the the ComparedProducts list. But, with there being no ViewState, this will get cleared on every page refresh and lose the last product. I want products to be kept in this ComparedProducts list, but how?

I'm guessing they need to be appended to the querystring, so /Carousel/Compare/?id=2122,1221,1331,1333 etc. If so, how is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

**Updated**

If I *did* want to go the query string route, how do I do this?

I've tried:

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Compare", "Compare", new { id = product.ProductId, compared = Model.ComparedProducts.Select(a => a.ProductId) })</td>
```

But that brings out:

```
compared=System.Linq.Enumerable%2BWhereSelectListIterator`2[Product%2CSystem.Int32]
```

Which I'd expect really. I guess I'd make yet a further ViewModel property and simply store the Compared Id's in there to not have much business logic within my View?

Comment: you want to post several values to the server, even using webforms would you ever use the querystring for this operation?

Take a look in the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection(v=vs.108).aspx and what's posted if you add this in your Controller

Comment: as far as i remember viewstate also doesn't survive a page refresh. It would only survive a POST request, as this submits the page contents to the server, including the viewstate. The equivalent of that would be some hidden field that contains your selected ids (or the list control itself, as it should already contain the selected IDs as its value), which would be received by the controller handling the POST request.

Comment: So, theoretically, the Compare hyperlink would be changed to a button and post back to the server, retaining the values in a hidden field in the View? What I'm looking for is how other people actually tackle this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for your relationship with webforms :)
I think from now on, you can start to keep state in the other ways you already know from webforms like Session State: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

You are also right on the querystring, after all, if you want to keep things simple, is better to use the simplest methods , for instance:

```
<url>?reference=123&compare=456
```

EXAMPLE

you need the first action as HttpGet and now this one as httpPOST

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Compare(myModel model)
{

    var product = SelectProduct(model.reference); // selects the product from a list of cached products.

    if (product != null)
    {
       // _productDetails is a Model specifically for my View.
       // you can always update the model you got in the first place and send it back
        model.ComparedProducts.Add(product); //
    }
return View("Index", model);
```

Your view should react according to empty properties to display

Comment: Just one further thing I'd like to know, in response to this, isn't it generally bad practice to be using Sessions within MVC?

Comment: not at all, keeping sessions is a valid method in every single website regardless of the technology you are using, either if you save your info in a cookie, in your server memory or a database, it all depends on your actual needs.

Comment: probably you mean scalability, but you can choose how to work with sessions, like I said before, you could keep this data in a cookie, in your server memory (not so scalable) or in an external windows service, you have the freedom to take on.

Comment: Thank you! :) I've updated my question, do you know how I'd go about my solution if I tackled it from the QueryString path?

Comment: by the way, you can't handle an operation with querystring only, you have to perform a POST operation, so a GET operation should not change anything in your application, a GET operation is returns an unchanged state, given that you are changing your model, is not correct to do it in the GET operation

Comment: I'm guessing I have to use a button for my "Compare" functionality rather than a link. How do I actually know the "Compared" Product ID from this? i.e. <input type="button" value="Compare" /> instead of my ActionLink.

Comment: you have to give a name to your controls, but first you need to understand scaffolding: http://forums.asp.net/t/1703382.aspx/1

Comment: essentially by scaffolding, MVC will know how to populate the model for your action, so you will only have to work with your model as a parameter instead of worrying about how you named the controls yourself